# What is the fast way to get a list with the corresponding serial number with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to drop some columns, sometimes the columns name is hart to type, so I want to get a list or tuple or array with the corresponding serial number, then I can drop them with `df1.drop(df1.columns[[0, 1, 3]], axis=1)`.

What is the fast way with pandas to do it like this?

```
In [2]: df1.columns
Out[2]: Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 3', '上班', '下班',
       '上班.1', '下班.1', 'Unnamed: 8', 'Unnamed: 9', 'Unnamed: 10',
       'Unnamed: 11'],
        dtype='object'
In [3]: a = df1.columns.tolist()
        b = list(range(len(df1.columns)))
        tuple(zip(a, b))
Out[3]: (('Unnamed: 0', 0),
        ('Unnamed: 1', 1),
        ('Unnamed: 2', 2),
        ('Unnamed: 3', 3),
        ('上班', 4),
        ('下班', 5),
        ('上班.1', 6),
        ('下班.1', 7),
        ('Unnamed: 8', 8),
        ('Unnamed: 9', 9),
        ('Unnamed: 10', 10),
        ('Unnamed: 11', 11))
In [4]: df1.drop(df1.columns[6:], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks. It returns  `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'enumerate'`, Shoud I do this `list(enumerate(df1.columns.tolist()))`?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I can't edit the former post, so I deleted it. `enumerate` is actually a built-in function, not a method of list objects. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a way to do it fast and easy:

```
for i, element in enumerate(df.columns):
    print(i, element)
```